# createGraphics in Instance Mode in p5js

Tags: p5.js

I'm new to p5.

My aim is to display ASCII value of the key I type and also leave a trail of vertical lines whose distance from left is 200+the ASCII value of the key,

which can be done using createGraphics() (adding an additional canvas layer on top with same dimensions as original and drawing on that additional canvas layer)

But the code doesn't seem to work and also it is not displaying any errors in the console.

```
const c5=function(p){

let pg;

p.setup=function(){
    p.createCanvas(600,400);
    pg=p.createGraphics(600,400);
};

p.draw=function(){
    p.background(200);
    p.textAlign(p.CENTER,p.TOP);
    p.textSize(20);
    p.text('ASCII Value : '+p.keyCode,300,100);

    pg.line(200+p.keyCode,200,200+p.keyCode,300);//shift right by 200
};
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you have to tell the engine that the thing you name `p` is actually a `p5` instance. You can construct a `p5` object using `new p5(...)` as follows:

```
const c5 = new p5(function(p) {

  p.setup = function(){
      ...
  };

  p.draw = function(){
      ...
  };
});
```

You then correctly fill up your `pg` graphic object with vertical lines. However, you do not "draw" it on your original canvas. You can do so using the p5.js `image()` function (see also the example shown in the [`createGraphics()` documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics)).

I've made a working example in the p5.js editor [here](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/1tAkC0mbd).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close. You are creating the graphic object and drawing to it but you also need to display it as an image to your canvas. In your code snippet you are also missing the call to create the new `p5js` object but that may be just a copy paste error.

Here is a working snippet of your code with the call to draw the image. I also moved the key detection logic to `keyPressed` so the logic only runs when a key is pressed.

Also notice that running the logic inside of `keyPressed` allows the sketch to handle keys such as `f5` by returning false and preventing default behavior. In a real application we would need to be very careful about overriding default behavior. Here we assume that the user wants to know the key code of the f5 key and will be ok with the page not reloading. In a real application that might not be the case.

```js
const c5=function(p){

let pg;

p.setup=function(){
    p.createCanvas(600,400);
    pg=p.createGraphics(600,400);
};

p.draw=function(){

};

p.keyPressed = function() {
    p.background(200);
    p.textAlign(p.CENTER,p.TOP);
    p.textSize(20);
    p.text('ASCII Value : '+p.key + " " +p.keyCode,300,100);
    pg.line(200+p.keyCode,200,200+p.keyCode,300);//shift right by 200
    p.image(pg, 0, 0);
   
  return false; // prevent default
}


};
var myp5 = new p5(c5)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```